# Uses of past perfect and past indefinite

Tags: tense, past-perfect, past-simple

> several years after father had retired on a pension, an accountant came to India to examine. He discovered that father had never applied for overdue bonuses.

My question is that why is he not writing in simple past only? Sometimes he uses simple past, sometimes past perfect. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

In narrative (telling a story), the simple past is typically used as the anchor to time periods in which the “main” events of the story happen:

> Kim left home in the afternoon. She drove on the long and winding road to her parents’ home for seven hours. When she finally arrived she was very tired and fell asleep the moment her head touched the pillow.

When something happened before one of those time periods, the past perfect can be used to show the relative order:

> Kim left home in the afternoon. By the time she arrived at her parents’ house, she had driven for seven hours on the long and winding road. She fell asleep the moment her head touched the pillow because the drive had tired her so.

Had driven occurred before the period in which arrived is anchored.

Had tired occurred before the period in which fell (and touched) are anchored.

Answer (score 0):

When we want to mention two events happened in the past, with respect to show which happened before the other, We would use **past perfect**.

And we usually use after and before with past perfect and it goes this way.

Imagine you had two events in the past

Event **1** ➡️ first happened.

Event **2** ➡️ second happened.

> [**Before** + past tense **<sub>event(2)</sub>** ], [past perfect **<sub>event(1)</sub>**]
>
> [**After** past perfect **<sub>event(1)</sub>**], [past tense **<sub>event(2)</sub>**]

Consider the following examples

> - **After** the family had had breakfast, they went to the zoo.
> - Jane had read a lot about elephant  **before** she went to the zoo.

Reread your piece of writing this way:

[(several years **after** father **had retired** on a pension **<sub>event(1)</sub>** ), an accountant **came** to india to examine  **<sub>event(2)</sub>**. 
[(He **discovered** **<sub>event(2)</sub> )  ) (that father **had never applied** for overdue bonuses **<sub>event(2)</sub>** )].

Answer (score 0):

That's because the Past perfect indicates something that is happened before the main event or the other event in the sentence